# How to avoid multiple stamps of the same output

Tags: c, printf

I'm encountering a problem with the output part where I send out the count of how many words have the same length. If two or more words have the same length, I get multiple outputs regarding those words, instead of just one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Write a program that captures using the gets function a string of maximum
5 words separated by spaces, for a total of up to 60 characters. The
program must:
a. Determine how many words are actually contained in the string
b. Calculate the average length of the words
c. Produce a statistic on the length of the words. 

If the input string is “this string contains five words”, the
program will print on the screen:
The string contains 5 words
The average word length is 5.4 characters
The string contains
2 words of 4 characters     <- at the moment this line gets printed twice for some reason
1 word of 5 characters
1 word of 6 characters
1 word of 8 characters*/


#define N 61
int main()
{
    char str[N]={0};
    int  wc[5]={0};
    int  dup[5]={0};
    int i=0, j=0, k=0, m=0, n=0, x, count=0, z=0, y=0;
    float avg=0, sum=0;

    printf("Introduce a string of [AT MOST] 5 words (60 characters): \n");
    fgets(str, N, stdin);

//word count + word length
    for (i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
         if (isalpha(str[i]))
            {
            count++;
            while (isalpha(str[i]))
              {
               k++;
               i++;
              }
            }
         if ((isdigit(str[i])) || (ispunct(str[i])) || (isspace(str[i])) || (str[i] != '\0'))
            {
             wc[j]=k;
             j++;
             k=0;
            }
        }
     printf("\nThere are %d words in the sentence.\n\n", count);

// checking for duplicates (same word length) 
    for (m=0; m<5 && wc[m]!=0; m++)
          { x=0;
           sum=(sum+wc[m]);
           for (n=0; n<5; n++)
              {
                if (wc[m]==wc[n]  &&  m!=j)
                    x++;
               }
           dup[y]=x;
           y++;
          }
     for (z=0; z<5 && dup[z]!=0; z++)
         {
          printf("%d word/s contain %d characters.\n", dup[z], wc[z]);
         }

     avg=sum/m;
     printf("\n\nThe average length of the words in the sentence is %.2f characters.\n\n", avg);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see I have added the visited arr and I have modified the second for loop.
This solution is just to edit your code to point out the error.
The better choice would have been to sort the wc array, and then linear scan the sorted output, as the duplicates will be together.

```
int main()
{
  char str[N]={0};
  int  wc[5]={0};
  int  dup[5]={0};
  int i=0, j=0, k=0, m=0, n=0, x, count=0, z=0, y=0;
  float avg=0, sum=0;
  int visited[5] = {0};
  printf("Introduce a string of [AT MOST] 5 words (60 characters): \n");
  fgets(str, N, stdin);

  //word count + word length
  for (i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
      if (isalpha(str[i]))
    {
      count++;
      while (isalpha(str[i]))
        {
          k++;
          i++;
        }
    }
      if ((isdigit(str[i])) || (ispunct(str[i])) || (isspace(str[i])) || (str[i] != '\0'))
    {
      wc[j]=k;
      j++;
      k=0;
    }
    }
  printf("\nThere are %d words in the sentence.\n\n", count);

  // checking for duplicates (same word length) 
  for (m=0; m<5 && wc[m]!=0; m++)
    { x=0;
      sum=(sum+wc[m]);

      if (!visited[m]) {
    visited[m] = 1;

    for (n=0; n<5 && wc[n]!=0; n++)
      {
        if (wc[m]==wc[n]  &&  m!=j) {
          if (!visited[n]) {
        visited[n]=1;
          }
        x++;
        }
      }
      }
      dup[y]=x;
      y++;
    }
  for (z=0; z<5; z++)
    {
      if (dup[z]!=0) {
    printf("%d word/s contain %d characters.\n", dup[z], wc[z]);
      }
    }

  avg=sum/m;
  printf("\n\nThe average length of the words in the sentence is %.2f characters.\n\n", avg);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: One question though...what's the role of <(!visited[m])> as I've never seen it before...?

Comment: @Robert the purpose of visited is to ensure that we will not count the index which has already been visited. But as I mentioned, the proper solution will to sort the wc array, then all the number with same word count will be consecutive. Then linear scan will do the job in a very clean fashion.

Comment: yeah...I understood that...I just didn't got that sintax...the !(something)..just so I can use it in other cases.

Comment: When visited[m] is 0, !visited[m] = 1. !(expression) simply invert 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.